# Query Items by Type

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, filter

I'm having trouble with queries in my app. If you look at [this page](http://www.willcountygreen.com/recycling_centers.aspx) you'll notice the 'Search by Item' drop-down is blank and the 'Search by Category' displays 'Select one' by default. And when you select a Category with only one Item, such as 'Bicycle Reuse-Donation', the 'Search by Item' drop-down sets itself to that one item. How do I replicate this?

I've been messing around in this section for hours. I can't figure it out? Here's [the app on Code Pen](https://codepen.io/underjollyroger/pen/XWXPgqm).

```
// Add the unique values to the recycle type
    // select element. This will allow the user
    // to filter categories by type.
    function addToSelect(values) {
        var dOpt = document.createElement("option");
        dOpt.value = "";
        dOpt.selected = true;
        dOpt.text = "Select one";
        catTypeSelect.add(dOpt);
        values.uCatVals.sort();
        values.uCatVals.forEach(function (value) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = value;
            catTypeSelect.add(option);
        });

        var dOpt2 = document.createElement("option");
        dOpt2.value = "";
        dOpt2.disabled = true;
        dOpt2.selected = true;
        dOpt2.text = "Select one";
        keyTypeSelect.add(dOpt2);
        values.uKeyVals.sort();
        values.uKeyVals.forEach(function (value) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = value;
            keyTypeSelect.add(option);
        });

        return setDefinitionExpression();
    }
    // re-query the layer based on the selected Category and re-populate the keyword select
    function addToSelect2(values) {
        while (keyTypeSelect.options.length > 0) {
            keyTypeSelect.remove(0)
        }
        var dOpt2 = document.createElement("option");
        dOpt2.value = "";
        dOpt2.disabled = true;
        dOpt2.selected = true;
        dOpt2.text = "Select one";
        keyTypeSelect.add(dOpt2);
        values.sort();
        values.forEach(function (value)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = value;
            keyTypeSelect.add(option);
        });
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I was looking at the pen and it seems to me its is working, what is the problem you are trying to solve? what it is not happening in your code that you expect to happen?

Comment: For example, when you select 'Bicycle Reuse/Donate' from Category in the app you see 'Select one' as the Item. Because there is only one item in this category, I'd like to already see 'Bicycles' as the item before clicking on the drop-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly, when there is only one option you don't want the "Select one" option.

If that is the case then it is pretty straight forward, just don't add that option. Something like this should work.

```
function addToSelect2(values) {
    while (keyTypeSelect.options.length > 0) {
        keyTypeSelect.remove(0)
    }

    // HERE
    // only add "Select one" if there are more than one option
    if (values.length > 1) {
      var dOpt2 = document.createElement("option");
      dOpt2.value = "";
      dOpt2.disabled = true;
      dOpt2.selected = true;
      dOpt2.text = "Select one";
      keyTypeSelect.add(dOpt2);  
    }
    
    values.sort();
    values.forEach(function (value)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = value;
        keyTypeSelect.add(option);
    });
    
    return true;
}
```